# macOS "No iCloud account is configured"

Tags: ios, macos, icloud, cloudkit

I'm writing an app on Xcode with both iPhone and Mac components, and trying to use CloudKit as an easy way to synchronize data between the users' devices.

Everything works great in the iOS version, but on the Mac version for some reason I'm getting an error that says: `No iCloud account is configured` even though I'm signed into iCloud.

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Is iCloud Drive enabled on your Mac sign in?

Comment: Nope. Is that related?

Comment: Yes. CloudKit needs iCloudDrive if you are using private data

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. Specifically, in System Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Drive > Options, you need to have Xcode.app checked (or I guess Xcode-beta.app if that's what you're using). As well as having iCloud Drive enabled of course. Note that this is also the case if you want to write to the public database, not just for the private DB (queries to the public database still seem to work with iCloud Drive turned off though).